# Force decimal point instead of comma in HTML5 number input (client-side)

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, numbers, decimal

I have seen that some browsers localize the `input type="number"` notation of numbers.

So now, in fields where my application displays longitude and latitude coordinates, I get stuff like "51,983" where it should be "51.982559". My workaround is to use `input type="text"` instead, but I'd like to use the number input with correct display of decimals.

Is there a way to **force browsers to use a decimal point** in the number input, regardless of client-side local settings?

(It goes without saying that in my application I anyway correct this on the server side, but in my setup I also need it to be correct on the client side (because of some JavaScript)).

***UPDATE***
As of right now, checking in Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m on Windows 7, the number input just does not accept decimals formatted with a comma. Proposed suggestions with the `step`attribute do not seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/AsJsj/

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I am experiencing almost the same problem on Chrome 11 on Windows.

Comment: No solution yet. Best guess is to avoid this (and use input type="text") untill this is fixed...

Comment: Looks like is dependent of the locales of your browser, in my chrome I see comma, in my partner's chrome I see dot.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24423879/196210

Comment: As i have also recently found out, some countries use comma instead of a 'decimal point.

Comment: That's exactly the point! Client locale settings force comma in countries where they use comma. I'm living in such a country and now wish to use the input with a decimal point.

Comment: @jbutler483 yes we do, but some of us try not to. what is annoying is that the people who set these 'standards' assume this is how some countries do it

Answer (score 45):

With the ***step*** attribute specified to the precision of the decimals you want, and the ***lang*** attribute [which is set to a locale that formats decimals with ***period***], your html5 numeric input will accept decimals. eg. to take values like 10.56; i mean 2 decimal place numbers, do this:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" lang="en" value="1.99">
```

You can further specify the ***max*** attribute for the maximum allowable value.

***Edit***
Add a ***lang*** attribute to the input element with a locale value that formats decimals with point instead of comma

Comment: This still doesn't work :-( Client-side local values always transform the decimal point in a decimal comma, regardless of step, or value attribute. :-(

Comment: As I understand the question is not about having a decimal separator. The question is about having '.' instead of ',' when the locale of the client prefers ','.

Comment: no matter what decimal separator you use in the step attribute - the browser will still localise it. That is, with your example given - in most European countries the number displayed would be 10,56

Comment: I came back and re-read the question 5 years later and wondered why I provided the answer above. See the edit, please

Comment: It will also not work if the data is being saved using ajax.

Answer (score 34):

Currently, Firefox honors the language of the HTML element in which the input resides. For example, try this fiddle in Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/ashraf_sabry_m/yzzhop75/1/

You will see that the numerals are in Arabic, and the comma is used as the decimal separator, which is the case with Arabic. This is because the `BODY` tag is given the attribute `lang="ar-EG"`.

Next, try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/ashraf_sabry_m/yzzhop75/2/

This one is displayed with a dot as the decimal separator because the input is wrapped in a `DIV` given the attribute `lang="en-US"`.

So, a solution you may resort to is to wrap your numeric inputs with a container element that is set to use a culture that uses dots as the decimal separator.

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately it only seems to work in Firefox, not in Chrome (47.0.2526.106)

Comment: Even not in Firefox, in France

Comment: 1. Build a page fr-FR which contains a form en-US, try to enter a decimal number like 123.45 and bingo! input.value is empty. :-(

Comment: Firefox respects the language setting of the page. Chrome imposes the decimal separator of the OS or the browser? Edge imposes the decimal point, regardless of the language settings of page or browser or OS. What a mess.

Comment: You don't need the wrapper element. You can set the `lang` attribute directly on the input element.

Comment: there is no any effect  define lang or not. Please define es-ES and see result

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ What browser are testing on? It still doesn't work on Chrome

Comment: The `lang` attribute actually made the difference for me, thanks!

Comment: The first link does not use the lang attribute

Comment: @LeonardoSibela It does. Click on the HTML menu in the top left of the HTML editing part of the fiddle, a drop down menu will open that has the definition of the BODY tag

Answer (score 18):

According to the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.step.float), You can use `any` as the value of `step` attribute:

```
<input type="number" step="any">
```

Answer (score 7):

Use lang attribut on the input. Locale on my web app fr_FR, lang="en_EN" on the input number and i can use indifferently a comma or a dot. Firefox always display a dot, Chrome display a comma. But both separtor are valid.

Answer (score 6):

I found a blog article which seems to explain something related:
[HTML5 input type=number and decimals/floats in Chrome](https://www.isotoma.com/blog/2012/03/02/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/)

In summary:

- the `step` helps to define the domain of valid values
- the default `step` is `1`
- thus the default domain is integers (between `min` and `max`, inclusive, if given)

I would assume that's conflating with the ambiguity of using a comma as a thousand separator vs a comma as a decimal point, and your `51,983` is actually a strangely-parsed fifty-one thousand, nine hundred and eight-three.

Apparently you can use `step="any"` to widen the domain to all rational numbers in range, however I've not tried it myself.  For latitude and longitude I've successfully used:

```
<input name="lat" type="number" min="-90.000000" max="90.000000" step="0.000001">
<input name="lon" type="number" min="-180.000000" max="180.000000" step="0.000001">
```

It might not be pretty, but it works.

Comment: In that case it's a good thing I wrote a summary and then extrapolated, eh?

Comment: In my case GeolocationPosition.coords.latitude sometimes returns a `float` like `99.999999999999999`. So the input step will be: `step="0.000000000000001"` to be a valid `required` input

Comment: @Treedbox By the 5th decimal point, you get to 1 meter accuracy, 6th decimal point is 10cm accuracy. Anything after that (dependent on your situation) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, the coverage of this input field in the modern browsers is very low:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Therefore, I recommend to expect the fallback and rely on a heavy-programmatically-loaded input[type=text] to do the job, until the field is generally accepted.

So far, only Chrome, Safari and Opera have a neat implementation, but all other browsers are buggy. Some of them, don't even seem to support decimals (like BB10)!

Comment: Using a library like [number.js](http://numeraljs.com/) might help with the inherent problems of having multiple languages on this planet.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this helps but I stumbled here when searching for this same problem, only from an *input* point of view (i.e. I noticed that my `<input type="number" />` was accepting both a comma and a dot when typing the value, but only the latter was being bound to the angularjs model I assigned to the input).
So I solved by jotting down this quick directive:

```
.directive("replaceComma", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on("keydown", function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode === 188) {
                    this.value += ".";
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then, on my html, simply: `<input type="number" ng-model="foo" replace-comma />` will substitute commas with dots on-the-fly to prevent users from inputting invalid (from a javascript standpoint, not a locales one!) numbers. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Andrea, is there any way to do this without Angular JS? With jQuery for example?

Comment: Sure, I suppose you could write, on a per-number-input basis, something like `$("input[type=number]").on("keydown", function(e) { if(e.keyCode === 188) { this.value += "."; e.preventDefault(); }});` (once your page has fully loaded along with all the number inputs)

Comment: This snippet doesn't work on chrome (tested with v60). When typing `888,`, setting the `value` property throws a warning stating that `888.` is not a valid number (the regexp requires at least one number after the dot) and blanks the field. Typing a dot works though, probably because the input consider its value “in progress” and waits for more digits to be typed

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, the HTML5 `input type="number` always returns `input.value` as a `string`.

Apparently, `input.valueAsNumber` returns the current value as a floating point number.  You could use this to return a value you want.

See http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Javascript for this?

`$('input').val($('input').val().replace(',', '.'));`

Comment: On chrome with input[type = number] is not working.. comma is always shown.

Answer (score 1):

The below is a work arround to enable the input of a **comma** and replace it by a **dod**. It works very well for continious input of the user.

The idea is to have an input that can be parsed into a number "123." cannot be parsed, but "123.0" can be parsed, and so the type of the input can be changed back from "text" to "number" and it still works. The selection is "just" to enable continious input, so the user overwrites the additional number

HTML element:

```html
<input type="number" id="numberinput">
```

Javascript

```js
document.getElementById("numberinput").keydown = function(event)
{
    if (
        event.target.getAttribute('type') === "number" &&
        event.key === "," &&
        event.target.value.indexOf(".") === -1)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.setAttribute("type","text");
        event.target.value = event.target.value + ".0";
        event.target.setSelectionRange(event.target.value.length - 1, event.target.value.length);
        event.target.setAttribute("type","number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one option is `javascript parseFloat()`... 
never do parse a "`text chain" --> 12.3456` with point to a int... `123456` (int remove the point)
parse a text chain to a FLOAT...

to send this coords to a server do this sending a text chain. `HTTP` only sends `TEXT`

in the client keep out of parsing the input coords with "`int`", work with text strings

if you print the cords in the html with php or similar... float to text and print in html

Answer (score 0):

1) 51,983 is a string type number does not accept comma

so u should set it as text

```
<input type="text" name="commanumber" id="commanumber" value="1,99" step='0.01' min='0' />
```

replace , with .

and change type attribute to number

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $('#commanumber').val().replace(/\,/g, '.');   
    $('#commanumber').attr('type','number');   
    $('#commanumber').val(s);   
});
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/ydf3kxgu/

Hope this solves your Problem

Comment: Actually, setting type as text is indeed nearly the only solution to make point stay point. In conjunction with `pattern="\d+\.\d{2}"` I'd even call such UX acceptable... I'd drop the jquery part, though...

Answer (score 0):

I have written a custom piece of code to do this

If you want to replace `,` with `.`, remove **translate_decimals** functions completely.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[role="custom-number"]');
var bincr = document.querySelector('button[role="increment"]');
var bdecr = document.querySelector('button[role="decrement"]');

function translate_decimals(side = 0)
{
 input.value = (side == ',' ? input.value.replace('.',',') : input.value.replace(',','.'));
}
translate_decimals(',');

bincr.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 if (input.hasAttribute('max'))
 {
  if (input.value.substr(0,input.getAttribute('max').length) == input.getAttribute('max').substr(0,input.getAttribute('max').length))
  {
   return;
  }
  else
  {
   translate_decimals('.');
   let temp = input.value;
   input.value = "";
   input.value = (input.hasAttribute('step') ? (parseFloat(temp) + parseFloat(input.getAttribute('step'))) : temp++);
   translate_decimals(',');
  }
 }
});

bdecr.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 if (input.hasAttribute('min'))
 {
  if (input.value.substr(0,input.getAttribute('min').length) == input.getAttribute('min').substr(0,input.getAttribute('min').length))
  {
   return;
  }
  else
  {
   translate_decimals('.');
   input.value = (input.hasAttribute('step') ? (input.value - input.getAttribute('step')) : input.value--);
   translate_decimals(',');
  }
 }
});
```

```css
/* styling increment & decrement buttons */
button[role="increment"],
button[role="decrement"] {
 width:32px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" role="custom-number" step="0.01" min="0" max="0" lang="en" value="1.99">
<button role="increment">+</button>
<button role="decrement">-</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to ensure values can still be entered with a comma instead of a point as a decimal separator. This seems to be an age-old problem. Background info can be found following these links:

- https://www.slightfuture.com/webdev/html5-input-number-localization.html
- https://codepen.io/aminimalanimal/full/bdOzRG

I finally solved it with a little bit of jQuery. Replacing the commas with dots onChange. This seems to be working good so far in latest Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```
$('input[type=number]').each(function () {

  $(this).change(function () {

    var $replace = $(this).val().toString().replace(/,/g, '.');

    $(this).val($replace);

  })

});
```

Answer (score -1):

use the pattern

```
<input 
       type="number" 
       name="price"
       pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" 
       step="0.01"
       title="This should be a number with up to 2 decimal places."
>
```

good luck

Comment: Hi, just tested it out in Chrome 62.0.3202.94 on Windows 10. It doesn't work. When using the spinner buttons, the input reverts to comma instead of point (considering Belgian locale settings). Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Think u will need to set this globally in the Culture, so pick your local culture e.g. en-ZA, and it will set the time date, currency, etc all correct 4 all:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35564876)

Answer (score -3):

## HTML  step Attribute

```
<input type="number" name="points" step="3">
```

> Example: if step="3", legal numbers could be -3, 0, 3, 6, etc.

> Tip: The step attribute can be used together with the max and min attributes to create a range of legal values.

**Note:** The step attribute works with the following input types: *number, range, date, datetime, datetime-local, month, time and week.*

Comment: But... but the question is about decimal numbers, `step="3"` would limit input to only whole numbers. And setting `step="0.01"` still shows it as a coma ;c