# HTML5: Is there any way to change comma to space in input-type-number?

Tags: html, input, types, webforms, numbers

Is there any way to change comma to space in input-type-number? (without javascript)

by default it format(split) number with commas (,) after 3 digits.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force decimal point instead of comma in HTML5 number input (client-side)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178332/force-decimal-point-instead-of-comma-in-html5-number-input-client-side)

Comment: @robertc did you read the question you linked to? Definitely not a duplicate

Comment: @gnibbler the question I linked to is about changing the number format in a number input, this question is about changing the number format in a number field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any customization available for input-type-number.
It is only possible to switch between dot separation and without any separation.

So, to show number 93.991 use:

```
<input type="number" step="0.001">
```

or if it is required more precision (93.9911) use

```
<input type="number" step="0.0001">
```

or if it is required to use only whole numbers:

```
<input type="number" step="1">
<input type="number" step="0,5">
```

Tested in Google Chrome Version 34.0.1799.0 canary